# Why does this cycle make an empty row after checking one row?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is supposed to replace the letters ö,ä,õ,ü with different letters. After completing one row it produces an empty row and I don't know why. I have tried to understand it for some time, but I couldn't really understand why it doesn't give me desired output.

```
f = input("Enter file name: ")

file = open(f, encoding="UTF-8")

for sentence in file:
    sentence = sentence.upper()
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter == "Ä":
           lause = sentence.replace(letter, "AE")
        elif letter == "Ö" or täht == "Õ":
           lause = sentence.replace(letter, "OE")
        elif letter == "Ü":
           lause = sentence.replace(letter, "UE")
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: ..Is it possible that your input file has an empty line at the bottom?

Comment: There aren't any empty rows between rows in the input file

Comment: Reading each line in includes the trailing newline. Your `print()` also includes a newline so you will get an empty row. Try `print(sentence, end='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading each line in includes the trailing newline. Your `print()` also includes a newline so you will get an empty row. Try `print(sentence, end='')` as follows:

```
filename = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(filename, encoding="UTF-8") as f_input:
    for sentence in f_input:
        sentence = sentence.upper()

        for letter in sentence:
            if letter == "Ä":
               lause = sentence.replace(letter, "AE")
            elif letter == "Ö" or täht == "Õ":
               lause = sentence.replace(letter, "OE")
            elif letter == "Ü":
               lause = sentence.replace(letter, "UE")
        print(sentence, end='')
```

Note: using `with open(...` will also automatically close your file afterwards.

---

You might also want to consider the following approach:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8

filename = input("Enter file name: ")
replacements = [('Ä', 'AE'), ('ä', 'ae'), ('Ö', 'OE'), ('ö', 'oe'), ('Õ', 'OE'), ('õ', 'oe'), ('Ü', 'UE'), ('ü', 'ue')]

with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()

    for from_text, to_text in replacements:
        text = text.replace(from_text, to_text)

    print(text)
```

This does each replacement on the whole text rather than line by line. It also preserves the case.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that it would close the file automatically with that command since I have only seen command f.close().

Answer (score 1):

I won't fix your program, just try to answer why it doesn't do what you are expecting:

1. The program doesn't run: in line 14 the variable "täht" might be a typo, supposed to be "letter"
2. You store the result of replace() in variable "lause" but never use it
3. by default print() adds "\n" at the end, but you can override it (see help(print) in the python shell)

Comment: 1 and 2: Oh, my bad, forgot to translate these parts of the code. 3:  I'm actually surprised that I didn't realize that after that much time of trying to figure out why the code did that.